# conditional manipulating and summarising of rows

Tags: r

Ciao guys,

I have the following, simplified data frame.

```
obj <- data.frame (id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
  yr = c(1990, 1991, 1990, 1991, 1990, 1991, 1990, 1991),
  degree = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0)
  )
```

Note that my real ID's are named something like  `2.01811e+13`

What I would like to do is the following:

I would like to create a new dataframe where each `id` is just listed once and should contain either the value 1 or 0.

- value 1, if degree changes the first id observation is 1 and the second is 2.
- value 0, if value of degree maintains at 1
- not list it, if the id observations are something like 0,0 or 2,2.

it should look like this,

```
 id value
1   0 
2   1 
3   0 
4 do not list
```

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

obj %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(value = ifelse(first(degree) == 1 & nth(degree, 2) == 2, "1", 
                           ifelse(all(degree == 1), "0", "do not list")))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id value      
  <dbl> <chr>      
1     1 0          
2     2 1          
3     3 0          
4     4 do not list
```

Comment: Good soluiton my friend

Answer (score 3):

You can use `case_when`:

```
obj1 <- obj %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(value = case_when(first(degree)==1 & last(degree)==1 ~ "0",
                        first(degree)==1 & last(degree)==2 ~"1",
                        TRUE ~ as.character("do not list"))
  ) %>% 
  distinct(id, value)
```

Output:

```
     id value      
  <dbl> <chr>      
1     1 0          
2     2 1          
3     3 0          
4     4 do not list
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(obj)[, change := shift(degree,  type = 'lead') - degree, 
 id][, .(value = first(change), firstdeg = first(degree)),
    id][firstdeg == 1, .(id, value)]
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

obj %>% group_by(id) %>% 
        mutate(change = lead(degree)-degree) %>%
        summarize(value = first(change), firstdeg = first(degree)) %>%
        filter(firstdeg == 1) %>% select(id,value) %>%
        ungroup

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id value
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0
2     2     1
3     3     0
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
# create dataset to store results:
results <- data.frame(id=unique(obj$id),
                                index=as.numeric(rep("NA", length(unique(obj$id))))
                                )
# fill results$index:
for(i in 1:length(unique(obj$id))){
    temp.df <- subset(obj, id==unique(obj$id)[i])
    if(length(unique(temp.df$degree))==1 & unique(temp.df$degree)==1) {results$index[i] <- 0} else
        {if(temp.df$degree[1]==1 & temp.df$degree[2]==2) {results$index[i] <- 1} else 
            {results$index[i] <- "do not list"}}
}

results
```